# Pull data out of BigQuery via custom web page (NOT the built-in WebUI)

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to build a simple web-based front-end tool to get data out of BigQuery directly, preferably without a middle-tier-type web server application. I don't mean the WebUI tool that is available via the Google Console, but rather something that can authenticate from inside the web page, send a query based on user input, and return data as JSON/JavaScript array/etc.

This paper outlines an interesting approach by using the Polymer toolkit -- I understand some combination of a Google Authentication element, a query element, and a data-binding element? [Visualization At Scale](https://www.fisglobal.com/Solutions/Institutional-and-Wholesale/Broker-Dealer/-/media/FISGlobal/Files/Whitepaper/Market-Reconstruction-2-0-Visualization-at-Scale.pdf).

I found examples for Google authentication online, but don't see anything about the querying part. I don't see anything in Google's online BigQuery documentation about this, apart from the guide on using the WebUI, which isn't appropriate for this task. Any examples much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen the page on [Querying Data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#bigquery-async-query-nodejs)? It has examples of issuing queries using node.js, for instance. Without knowing much about your application, I'm assuming you would want to start the query (or queries) using the async API. The example that it gives, [a more complete version of which is also available on Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/bigquery/queries.js), is:

```
function asyncQuery (sqlQuery) {
  // Instantiates a client
  const bigquery = BigQuery();

  // Query options list: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/query
  const options = {
    query: sqlQuery,
    useLegacySql: false // Use standard SQL syntax for queries.
  };

  let job;

  // Runs the query as a job
  return bigquery.startQuery(options)
    .then((results) => {
      job = results[0];
      console.log(`Job ${job.id} started.`);
      return job.promise();
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log(`Job ${job.id} completed.`);
      return job.getQueryResults();
    })
    .then((results) => {
      const rows = results[0];
      console.log('Rows:');
      rows.forEach((row) => console.log(row));
      return rows;
    });
}
```

Comment: Tried node.js and it works really well in the background! Now just need to figure out how to get D3 to work with Node.js (D3 seems to work separately as a regular HTML page, but a bit tricky to integrate with Node.js). But this is another topic. The BigQuery part works great. Thanks!